# return a value out of an eventListener that is inside of a forof loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, return

How can I pass the returned coin object from the displayCurrencies function to the getCoinId function to use it as a parameter in the API call for retrieving the specific coin data?

this is the function i created to return the value:

```
let returnID = (value) => {
  return value;
};
```

this is the function that i want to return coin from:

```
let displayCurrencies = async () => {
  let coinsContainer = document.querySelector(`.coins`);
  try {
    let coins = await getData();
    let coinsArray = [];
    let coinElement;
    for (const coin of coins) {
      coinElement = coin;

      if (coinsArray.length > 20) {
        break;
      }
      coinsArray.push(coin);
      // create Nodes
      let coinDisplay = createElement(`li`, `coin`);
      let coinSymbolElement = createElement(`p`, `coinSymbol`);
      let coinIDElement = createElement(`p`, `coinID`);
      // set Values
      coinSymbolElement.innerHTML = coin.symbol;
      coinIDElement.innerHTML = coin.id;

      // append
      coinDisplay.append(coinSymbolElement, coinIDElement);
      coinsContainer.appendChild(coinDisplay);

      coinDisplay.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        openModal();
        returnID(coin);
      });
    }
    let returnCoin = returnID
    coinDisplay.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    console.log(returnCoin);
    });

    console.log(returnCoin);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

and last, this is the function that i want to use the returned value at:

```
displayCurrencies();
let getCoinId = async () => {
  let coinID = await displayCurrencies();
  let currencyData = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinID}`;
  let responseData = await fetch(currencyData);
  let dataOfCoins = await responseData.json();
  console.log(dataOfCoins);
};
```

Comment: You can't. The event listener doesn't run until the user clicks on the element, which happens long after this function has returned. The event listener function has to do everything that's needed with the user's input, not return it.

Comment: This is an async function so you should return a promise. Perhaps you may try creating a new Promise and store it's `resolve` function under a variable in the async function's context like `let v, p = new Promise(resolve => v = resolve);`  and return `p`. Then in the event listeners callback invoke the cached resolver like `x.addEventListener("click", _=> v(returnCoin))` kind of. In `displayCurrencies` function `coinID` will wait for `p` to resolve until it gets clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an onclick event for each element, and when the call-back is called you invoke the getCoinID function passing the coinID as a parameter.

A simple example:

```html
<ul class="coins">
</ul>

<script>
    function addOnClick() {
        let coinsContainer = document.querySelector('.coins');
        let coins = [
            { id: 1, symbol: 'bitcoin' },
            { id: 3, symbol: 'brazil-fan-token' },
            { id: 4, symbol: 'celo-euro' },
        ]

        for (const coin of coins) {
            let coinDisplay = document.createElement('li')
            let coinSymbolElement = document.createElement('p')
            let coinIDElement = document.createElement('p')

            coinSymbolElement.innerHTML = coin.symbol
            coinIDElement.innerHTML = coin.id

            coinDisplay.appendChild(coinIDElement)
            coinDisplay.appendChild(coinSymbolElement)

            coinsContainer.appendChild(coinDisplay)

            coinDisplay.addEventListener('click', () => {
                getCoinID(coin.symbol)
            })
        }
    }

    async function getCoinID(coinID) {
        let currencyData = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinID}`
        let responseData = await fetch(currencyData)
        let dataOfCoins = await responseData.json()
        console.log(dataOfCoins)
    }

    addOnClick()
</script>
```